# conflicts with firebase functions rewrite and vue router

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, vue-router

When I put the project of vue in public, the functions of firebase stop working and all the calls of these routes are redirected to the project vue

this is my firebase.js

```
{
    "hosting": {
      "public": "./dist/pwa-mat",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
    "rewrites": [ {
        "source": "/second", "function": "webPush"
      },{
        "source": "/subscribe", "function": "webPush"
      },{
        "source": "/hello/**", "function": "api"
      },{
        "source": "/subscribemsg/**", "function": "webPush"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      } ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling the rewrites by leaving only `"source": "**"` pointing to `/index.html` and using some client side rendering like Vue router?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, like what? Could you give me an example? Thank you. PD this is one function call https://us-central1-labuenosaires-7b80d.cloudfunctions.net/api/hello/martu

Comment: any idea? Frank pata puffelen?